# sidebar menu which scrolls down in sidebar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i saw this several times on other sites but wasnt able to find how to do it easily.

I have a website with a submenu in the left sidebar, now i want the menu-widget to stick inside the sidebar area at top of window when i scroll down, so the menu comes with down.

After reaching the end of the sidebar-area it should leave at the end and waiting to scroll up or refresh the site. When scrolling up it should stop at the top sidebar-area border.

`For better understanding:`
https://jsfiddle.net/6hrsod07/
i want the red menu scrolling with down inside of the light red area.

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: create a [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the fiddle for it: https://jsfiddle.net/2d4xhcqe/

This way it will stick to the top when you scroll down.

```
nav {
  background: #f00;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Give your `nav` element the `position: sticky;` property. This makes the `nav` element move with your scroll position based on the `top`, `bottom`, `left` and `right` values and makes it follow your viewport until it reaches the border of its parent.

```
nav {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  background: #f00;
}
```